# Converting Excel formula to VBA for Mid and Find functions

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, excel-formula

I'm really struggling on converting the excel formula below to VBA. The function below I would assume need to be within a for loop, and needs to descend down a dynamic column length. I've searched around trying to write the script myself, but I just can't seem to get it to run without an error.

=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,FIND("(",A1)-FIND(":",A1)-1)

Comment: You mean make this work in VBA? use range("a1") and replace FIND with instr  Mid(range(a1).value, instr(1,range("a1").value,":").....

Comment: Your title says VB Script, your text says VBA. What do you need?

Comment: VBA, sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column length (or last row) dynamically using the following:

```
dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("mySheetNameHere")
dim lastRow, myLoop, semicolPos, bracketPos
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' this gets last row in col A

For myLoop = 1 to lastRow
    ' Find the position of the ";"  and the "(" 
    semicolPos = InStr(ws.Range("A" & myLoop).Value, ":") + 1
    bracketPos = InStr(ws.Range("A" & myLoop).Value, "(")
    newValue = Mid(ws.Range("A" & myLoop).Value, semicolPos, bracketPos - semicolPos)
    ' Put newValue into column B, one cell over from column A
    ws.Range("B" & myLoop).Value = newValue
Next
```

Comment: Hey Dave, so probably a dumb question, but as that code parses through the cells in column A, I need the output of the code to be in B1, B2, etc. Do I use the offset function after "Next" in the above code?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Dave! I definitely wouldn't have been able to get that on my own. I really appreciate it.